# Setting Max and Min numbers for random in c++ srand

Tags: c++

In my program I am trying to simulate a roulette wheel spinning. Currently I have it setup to give me 38 random numbers but the number I get for all those numbers are the `max int 32767`

I think I am setting the `max and min` wrong but I can't figure out how.

I have made programs like this that work fine so I really would like to understand what I am missing here.

I am wondering if it has to do with my function that is displaying the random numbers after they are created.

my code is as followed,

```
int spin = 1;
int board;

double_clist cdl;

void Randomize() {
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ) ;  }

int Random(int Max) { return (rand() % Max) + 1;    }

int main() {

    int spin;
    Randomize();
    for(spin = 1; spin <= 38; spin++) {
        for (spin = 0; spin < 38; spin++) {
            board = Random(38);
            cdl.insert_begin();
            }
        }

    cdl.display();
```

This is my function for inserting each number in to the list,

```
void double_clist::insert_begin()
{
    int value;
    struct node *temp;
    temp = create_node(value);
    if (start == last && start == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"Element inserted in empty list"<<endl;
        start = last = temp;
        start->next = last->next = NULL;
        start->prev = last->prev = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->next = start;
        start->prev = temp;
        start = temp;
        start->prev = last;
        last->next = start;
        cout<<"Element inserted"<<endl;
    }
}
```

This is my function for displaying the list after I have created it,

```
void double_clist::display()
{
    int i;
    struct node *s;
    if (start == last && start == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"The List is empty, nothing to display"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    s = start;
    for (i = 0;i < counter-1;i++)
    {
        cout<<s->info<<"<->";
        s = s->next;
    }
    cout<<s->info<<endl;
}
```

Comment: You might be better off learning about the [C++ random library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random), specifically how to set up and use `std::uniform_int_distribution`.

Comment: Ok thanks I will look that up. Is my method not practical?

Comment: It's hard to say as you haven't included a compilable example, what does `create_node` do for instance?

Comment: It creates a new node in my linked list for the value.

Comment: Please post the code.

Comment: Note: if you're planning on generating a linked list for a roulette **wheel**, I can assure you the wheel order is anything-but-random. The only dependency of order is whether there is, or is not, a double-zero pocket on the wheel. The standard orders used in nearly all casinos [can be seen here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roulette#Roulette_wheel_number_sequence).

Comment: [OT]: Your double loop use `spin` twice and so you do only one loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The random number function is fine - must be something in the data structure.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void Randomize() {
    srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) ) ;  }

int Random(int Max) { return (rand() % Max) + 1;    }

int main() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        int val = Random(38);
        cout << val << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
Success time: 0 memory: 3296 signal:0
22 35 4 4 30 28 11 31 22 8 21 10 21 30 2 11 27 37 25 29
```

Comment: any help on how I can troubleshoot that? I am super lost with that news.

Comment: It looks like you insert `value` into your linked list without assigning the value of `board` to it first, so it has the unassigned value going into the list. I'd change your method to move value as a parameter `void double_clist::insert_begin(int value)`, then call it with the random number directly like `cdl.insert_begin(Random(38));`